# not in gzip format? downloading file for assembly class

Tags: assembly, terminal, hla

I have a mac and im taking assembly HLA for the first time. Im not really familiar with coding on my terminal so im a little lost.

these are the instructions after I download the file:

Issue the command: cd Downloads

Next, from Terminal, issue the command: gzip -d mac.hla.tar.gz

Next, from Terminal, issue the command: tar -xvf mac.hla.tar

but after the first command im getting the error "not in gzip format"??

I just want to download the file correctly. [code from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTd11.png)
mac.hla.tar.gz is the name of the file

Comment: You forgot to link the file you downloaded or say how you downloaded it. In the meantime, just try running the second `tar` command on it as it might already be decompressed.

Comment: oh sorry my professor had the link to the file and told us to keep it in downloads the name of the file is mac.hla.tar.gz in the info of the file it says kind: gzip compressed archive. when I run the second command it says "tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'mac.hla.tar'"

Comment: Try renaming the file to `mac.hla.tar` first.